# Why do my images not show up after I change the file name?

Tags: html, css, image, filenames, banner

I wanted to change the images I had on the top for banners, but once I changed the image, they do not show up anymore. Could somebody please check my code to see why they are not appearing?

```css
.sub-header{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/about-sub.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `quote-unquote` in your `url` and don't forget to close the curly bracket. Further reading about [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

```css
.sub-header{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url("/images/about-sub.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```